# How to configure Windows Activation Server (WAS) in Windows XP to host WCF services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, was

How do I configure Windows Activation Server(WAS) in Windows XP to host WCF services ?

Comment: Are you running IIS already?  What version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[WAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Activation_Services) was introduced in version 6.0 of Windows, or Server 2008 and Windows Vista.

Unfortunately it is not available for Windows XP or Server 2003. You'll need to upgrade your operating system to one that supports IIS 7.0. It is not available as a separate component.

Comment: Can we install separate WAS in Windows Xp

Comment: @user1573747 Unfortunately not. It is part of the operating system.